# What is the adjunction that generates the multiset monad on Set?

Tags: category-theory, monads, data-structure

The multiset monad is a triple $<M, \mu,\eta>$.

$M: Set \rightarrow Set$

$M$ sends a set to the set of all multisets on that set.

What is the adjunction that generates this monad?

I am looking for the two functors.  What are they?  Free and forgetful?

Comment: Commutative monoids.